# Is it is possible to reference existing data to create a chart using openpyxl?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, openpyxl

I have some data that is already in an xlsx sheet. Is it possible to build a chart using openpyxl with this data that already exists in these cells? The data gets updated monthly.

data

```
category    3/1/2021    3/8/2021
computer    2646        3000
network     117         200
other       316         20
total       3079        3220
```

[image]

Desired:

A chart month by month chart next to the data

[image]

Doing:

```
from datetime import date

from openpyxl import Workbook
from openpyxl.chart import (
    LineChart,
    Reference,
)
from openpyxl.chart.axis import DateAxis

wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active



c2 = LineChart()
c2.title = "Date Axis"
c2.style = 12
c2.y_axis.title = "Size"
c2.y_axis.crossAx = 500
c2.x_axis = DateAxis(crossAx=100)
c2.x_axis.number_format = 'd-mmm'
c2.x_axis.majorTimeUnit = "days"
c2.x_axis.title = "Date"

c2.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)
dates = Reference(ws, min_col=1, min_row=2, max_row=5)
c2.set_categories(dates)

ws.add_chart(c2, "E1")
```

Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#pull in your data
wb_obj = load_workbook(path)
sheet_obj = wb_obj.active

c1 = BarChart()
c1.title = "Test"
c1.y_axis.title = "Test1"
c1.x_axis.title = "Test2"

#reference your data
data = Reference(sheet_obj, min_col=2, min_row=2, max_col=3, max_row=5)
c1.add_data(data, titles_from_data=True)

#save the data
sheet_obj.add_chart(c1, "E1")
wb_obj.save("samples.xlsx")
```